# SharePoint Workflow Logic When New Item Is Created

Tags: workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, lookup-column, approval-process

Background: I am using SharePoint 2013. I do not have admin-rights to SPD, because I am at a large company where SPD access is not granted to everyone. However, on Friday I am meeting with the dev-team to present our workflow, but I would like to go into it with some direction to gear them towards.

Issue: I have created an InfoPath form on our site. A field within this form is the company name they work for. (There are 4 companies to choose from, which are part of the parent company I work for). When the form is submitted, this company name field becomes a column to the right of the InfoPath form item in the library. What I need my workflow to do is the following: When a new item is created (a form is submitted), the task of approving the form is assigned to an email address that is looked up based off the company name field/column. I have tried to do this with the access I have, and have failed thus far because I can only enter in email addresses into the "Assigned to" field of my workflow, not any lookup formulas, etc. This is why I have called upon the help of our development team.

So, what I need to know is...

1.) What I am trying to do is NOT possible without SPD, correct?

2.) When I meet with our IS development team on this, what direction do I point them in? I obviously have all of this diagrammed out as a business plan. But, because I don't know what the SPD side of SharePoint looks like, and the IS team is on the other side of the country, I would like to go in with an idea of what SPD tools/features we should work with so I can make the most of my time, and not waste theirs.

Thanks for all of your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding **the task of approving the form is assigned to an email address that is looked up based off the company name field/column. I have tried to do this with the access I have, and have failed thus far because I can only enter in email addresses into the "Assigned to" field of my workflow,**

It's applicable as the following

- Add Assign Task or Start Task Process Action > click on these users > Click on Receptions button > Workflow Lookup for a user > Current item > Select your lookup field > Ok > Add.

[image]

**Regarding What I am trying to do is NOT possible without SPD, correct?**

No, it's not correct you can create an `Event Receiver` at `Item Added` but it will need programming and more time to do it.

**Regarding what SPD tools/features we should work with so I can make the most of my time, and not waste theirs.**

Simply Microsoft SharePoint Designer (SPD), formerly known as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer, is a discontinued HTML editor freeware specialized in creating or modifying Microsoft SharePoint sites, workflows and web pages.

Comment: I believe I am following you correctly. One question: What version of SharePoint are you showing me in the your screenshot? Are you using SharePoint Designer to do that as well?

Comment: SharePoint Designer  2013 with SharePoint 2013 workflow platform, please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. It all makes sense to me and hopefully I can obtain SharePoint Designer access in my meeting today or get the support I need from my IS team.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a workflow with SPD you do not need admin rights, only full control (site ownership). I believe what you are asking can be done with a combination of infopath and SPD, just you need 2 lists where you have the main form and the parallel list with the company name and email related to that company.

Comment: Pretty sure you only need Designer permissions to the site, not Full Control. And by "parallel" list, this means you create a custom list and create a column of type "Lookup" in your InfoPath Form Library. After that, you can follow M.Qassas' screenshots.